# Why is the bitwise AND of two of the same value producing a different value?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have noticed a weird behaviour using bitwise AND operator in JS:

```js
console.log((0xd41ddb80 & 0xd41ddb80).toString(16))
```

The result is -2be22480, but I was expecting 0xd41ddb80

What can be the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.

When interpreted as a signed 32-bit integer, the value `0xd41ddb80` represents the number `-736240768`. Using any bitwise operator on this number will coerce it into a signed 32-bit integer:

```js
console.log(0xd41ddb80)


console.log(~~0xd41ddb80)
console.log(0xd41ddb80 & 0xffffffff)
console.log(0xd41ddb80 | 0)
```

The the base-16 equivalent of `-736240768` is `-2be22480`, and that is what you are seeing .

You can observe similar behavior for any number greater than or equal to `0x80000000`.